# Getting an error on pcolormesh (matplotlib) for masked array but my arrays aren't masked?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to use matplotlib and basemap to plot temperature data from a netcdf file. My plotting code is:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
m = Basemap(projection='lcc', resolution='c',
            width=8E6, height=8E6, 
            lat_0=45, lon_0=-100,)
m.shadedrelief(scale=0.5)
m.pcolormesh(lon2, lat2, t2m,
             latlon=True, cmap='RdBu_r')
plt.clim(-8, 8)
m.drawcoastlines(color='lightgray')

plt.title('January 2014 Temperature Anomaly')
plt.colorbar(label='temperature anomaly (°C)');
```

I keep getting the following error output:

[image]

[image]

i.e. the error points to the pcolormesh line, tests if both X and Y are masked arrays, and throws the error saying x and y cannot have non-finite values or be masked. However, if I test

```
np.ma.is_masked(lon2)
np.ma.is_masked(lat2)
```

both are false. Similarly neither contains either infinite or nan values. Any suggestions? I can post full replication code and data if helpful.

Update: Code below and data attached

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

data = Dataset('ERA5_1959.nc')

lat = data.variables['latitude'][:]
lon = data.variables['longitude'][:]
lon, lat = np.meshgrid(lon, lat)
t2m = data.variables['t2m'][1,1,:,:] #temp data

#create non-masked arrays
lon2 = lon.filled()
lat2 = lat.filled()

#plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
m = Basemap(projection='lcc', resolution='c',
            width=8E6, height=8E6, 
            lat_0=45, lon_0=-100,)
m.shadedrelief(scale=0.5)
m.pcolormesh(lon2, lat2, t2m2,
             latlon=True, cmap='RdBu_r')
plt.clim(-8, 8)
m.drawcoastlines(color='lightgray')

plt.title('January 2014 Temperature Anomaly')
plt.colorbar(label='temperature anomaly (°C)');
```

Data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/czb7x1qen2snokf/ERA5_1959.nc?dl=0

Comment: @BigBen updated to include data & code

Comment: `t2m2` is not defined in your code snippet. Can I assume that it would be something like `t2m2 = t2m.filled()`, like with the other arrays?

Comment: @molinav yes apologies - forgot to switch that back after changing t2m didn't make a difference

Comment: You are probably hitting a corner case in the library that needs to be fixed. The variables `x` and `y` in your traceback are in the projected system and not in lat-lon as your inputs. I added some debugging lines in my `basemap` and in fact `np.min(x), np.max(x), np.min(y), np.max(y)` returns to me `-550329843.5950986, inf, -543960904.2919441, inf`, so the arrays `x` and `y` get overflowed and masked inside the `m.pcolormesh` method. I would suggest that you open an issue in the GitHub repo, so that I do not forget to revise it and fix it: https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues